# liferay sub domains are not redirecting after some time

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, c3p0

I am using Liferay 6.2 I have created multiple portal instances(Subdomains) using database sharding

It needs server restart and all subdomains will work properly again after restarting server.

I am using Liferay 6.2 and I have used Liferay shards for creating portal instances'.
I am getting the following exception if I access by adding host file entry.

Any help appreciated thanks in advance.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: xxxxxxx at

java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:635)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:934)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1302)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.jsp.get_005fimage_005fpath_jsp._jspService(get_005fimage_005fpath_jsp.java:545)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:295)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doInclude(IncludeTag.java:192)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:83)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TagTransformModel$TagWriter.endEvaluation(TagTransformModel.java:430)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TagTransformModel$TagWriter.afterBody(TagTransformModel.java:417)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:312)
        at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:310)
        at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
        at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
        at com.liferay.portal.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplate.processTemplate(FreeMarkerTemplate.java:122)
        at com.liferay.portal.template.AbstractTemplate.processTemplate(AbstractTemplate.java:108)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.doIncludeFTL(ThemeUtil.java:344)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.doDispatch(ThemeUtil.java:169)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.includeFTL(ThemeUtil.java:113)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.include(ThemeUtil.java:96)
        at com.liferay.taglib.theme.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:34)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay_002dtheme_005finclude_005f1(portal_jsp.java:572)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspService(portal_jsp.java:515)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsUtil.forward(StrutsUtil.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.doForward(PortalRequestProcessor.java:279)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:341)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:173)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:546)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:523)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.sendError(PortalImpl.java:6556)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.sendError(PortalUtil.java:1850)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:134)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:359)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:408)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:70)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:263)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.monorail.url.filter.URLFilter.doFilter(URLFilter.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1098.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy853.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On click of generate thread dump in sever administration getting following logs

```
28:47,726 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-16427][EditServerAction:610] __Full thread dump of OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 24.111-b01 on Thu May 30 08:28:47 
 __"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->UQYtaf6w]-HelperThread-#7" (main), priority=5, id=224, state=TIMED_WAITING_
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)_        
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)__
"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->H3c3TImH]-HelperThread-#8" (main), priority=5, id=104, state=TIMED_WAITING_ java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)_   
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)__
"C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->QEiK7UfZ]-HelperThread-#3" (main), priority=5, id=26, state=TIMED_WAITING_      
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)_   com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)__"http-bio-8080-exec-14251" (main), priority=5, id=15445, state=WAITING_  
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)_  
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1465)_   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)_    
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)_  
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)_ com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)_       com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)_ org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:403)
    _       org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)_   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)_  org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)_      org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)_   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)_ org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)_   
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)_   
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
_org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)_  
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)_  
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)_     
org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)_  
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)_              org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)_     
org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)_ 
com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:177)_  
com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:168)_       com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SQLQueryImpl.iterate(SQLQueryImpl.java:140)_     
com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SQLQueryImpl.iterate(SQLQueryImpl.java:132)_    com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.service.persistence.KaleoTaskInstanceTokenFinderImpl.countKaleoTaskInstanceTokens(KaleoTaskInstanceTokenFinderImpl.java:79)_      
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor893.invoke(Unknown Source)_  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)_       
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)_       
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:320)_  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)_   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)_  
com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice.invoke(ShardPersistenceAdvice.java:101)_  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
_org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
_org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)_       org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)_  
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy905.countKaleoTaskInstanceTokens(Unknown Source)_   com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.service.impl.KaleoTaskInstanceTokenLocalServiceImpl.searchCount(KaleoTaskInstanceTokenLocalServiceImpl.java:575)_  com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.service.impl.KaleoTaskInstanceTokenLocalServiceImpl.searchCount(KaleoTaskInstanceTokenLocalServiceImpl.java:538)_  com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.service.impl.KaleoTaskInstanceTokenLocalServiceImpl.searchCount(KaleoTaskInstanceTokenLocalServiceImpl.java:525)_  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor939.invoke(Unknown Source)_       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)_  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)_     
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)_     com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)_        com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)_ com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)_     
com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)_  
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy903.searchCount(Unknown Source)_ 
    com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.service.KaleoTaskInstanceTokenLocalServiceUtil.searchCount(KaleoTaskInstanceTokenLocalServiceUtil.java:511)_       com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.WorkflowTaskManagerImpl.getWorkflowTaskCountByUserRoles(WorkflowTaskManagerImpl.java:353)_ sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor882.invoke(Unknown Source)_ sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)_   \
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)_  org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:320)_  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)_
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)_   
com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:48)_ org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)_ 
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)_   
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)_   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)_    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy915.getWorkflowTaskCountByUserRoles(Unknown Source)_
```

Comment: the exception look like some network connection problems. You you verify with curl/wget that the host mentioned  with `java.net.UnknownHostException` is reachable? Maybe the name is not resolveable?

Comment: Could you add the logs from liferay so we can see exceptions from the server side?

Comment: these are the only logs in the server, no other logs can you suggest what is happening why it works again after restart